# C# Handling Null Value When Parsing DateTime for Year

Tags: c#

I have a simple console app that I'm trying to parse the year value from a DateTime? type object that returns mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss am/pm

The following code works until I come across an entry that is null for the date

```cs
public void movieSearch(string mov)
{
    SearchContainer<SearchMovie> results = client.SearchMovieAsync(mov).Result;
    Console.WriteLine($"Got {results.Results.Count:N0} of {results.TotalResults:N0} results");
    foreach (SearchMovie result in results.Results)                
        Console.WriteLine($"Moive Title: {result.Title},  Movie ID: {result.Id},  Release Date: {(result.ReleaseDate).Value.Year}");
}
```

How can I handle nulls for result.ReleaseDate?
As I mentioned, the type for that object is DateTime? which I believe the "?" means nullable. I'm assuming it's allowing nulls.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well want to you *want* to print in that case? You could easily have different statements for if `result.ReleaseDate` is null or not... or you could effectively provide a default. But without knowing what you're trying to achieve, I'm reluctant to write an answer...

Comment: DateTime has no format, it's a binary type. I suspect `result.ReleaseDate` is a `DateTime?` which is an alias for `Nullable<DateTime>`. You can use `result.ReleaseDate?.Year` to get the year if the property has a value, `null` otherwise. You'll have to decide what to post instead of that null though. If you use `?.Year` you'll get an empty string. `{result.ReleaseDate?.Year ?? 0}` is possible, generating `Release Date: 0`.

Comment: As another note, your title talks about *parsing* a `DateTime`. The code you've provided here isn't doing any parsing - could you either remove the reference to parsing from the title, or clarify what you mean by it? (Note that "from a DateTime? type object that returns mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss am/pm" is also somewhat meaningless - a `DateTime` value doesn't have a format, any more than an `int` is decimal or hex. How it is converted to a string by default depends on the culture you run the code in, but it's not part of the value.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a `DateTime?`, you can check for null:

```
Console.WriteLine($"Moive Title: {result.Title},  Movie ID: {result.Id},  Release Date: {(result.ReleaseDate)?.Value.Year.ToString() ?? "Unknown"}");
```

Comment: I doubt that will compile, given that the `??` operands are of type `int?` and `string` here.

Comment: @JonSkeet This did compile and actually worked once I removed the ".Value".

Comment: @ronniej962: At the time when I commented, it didn't have `.ToString()`.

Comment: I snuck a little fix in